Installing new nvme drives; now, Windows won't boot
Also updated the Asus mobo BIOS at the same time.  This is primarily a winblows machine (since the VR headset is not supported yet (any day now -- for over a year)).  I installed the nvme drive as a dual-boot system, with Ubuntu as default.  Gparted shows that the NTFS partitions are still there and flagged as bootable, but they will NOT boot and do not show up as bootable in the BIOS!  I am stumped.  It's a lot of trouble to mechanically remove the nvme drive now so that has to be last-resort for testing.  
I've tried a few things with "testdisk" but nothing real drastic yet.
Oh, and Grub is not showing any windows bootable partitions but it does show the correct amounts of Linux partitions.
I'm very hesitant to try "Fdisk" on the windows drive as I am concerned about further bricking the windows partitions (no backup )
Thanks for any help.

First, welcome to Ask. Please append to you question the result of command 'mokutil --sb' (Checking if secure boot is enabled.) If it is you could try turning it off in BIOs to see if it will boot then.

I finally invoked "boot-repair" and it helped somewhat, but there are still problems.  I can start Windows10 again and sometimes it stays up for a whole 30 minutes!  Woohoo (sarcasm).  I threw away all my knowledge of Windows a couple years ago and having to relearn all the system things to get it running reliably again.  I hate Windows, esp 10.
